# Как заблокировать только горизонтальную автопрокрутку?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как заблокировать только горизонтальную автопрокрутку и оставить автопрокрутку вертикальную?

`e.Handled = true;` это блокируют сразу любую автопрокрутку отключая и вертикальную.
При этом item.BringIntoView для вертикальной также отключается.

отключает всё

```
EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>


private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

автопрокрутка вертикальной и горизонтальной. Но нужна только вертикальная

```
<Setter Property="localModels:TreeViewItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />

static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
        // whose IsSelected property was modified. Ignore all ancestors
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Использую

```
 scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
```

он работает только для коротких item, но он не работает для длинных item. Длинные item всёравно уходят вправо.

Comment: Минимальный пример кода, на котором можно всё это испробовать приведите

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"

Comment: Мне нужно не отключить горизонтальную прокрутку, а отключить только горизонтальную  `автопрокрутку` при выборе item